# Inside of a web browser or Node, why does an event not occur if you don't listen on it, but once you listen on it, it happens?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

The event I looked at was `voiceschanged`. You can load up `about:blank` or any webpage that doesn't do speech, and wait for 10 minutes, and do a single `window.speechSynthesis.getVoices()` and it is still an empty array. So `voiceschanged` never happened for that 10 minutes.

But again refresh your page, and open up that same webpage or `about:blank` again, once you listen on `voiceschanged`, the event will happens:

```
window.speechSynthesis.addEventListener('voiceschanged', function(ev) {
  console.log(window.speechSynthesis.getVoices())
});
```

How do you understand this behavior? (in a browser or Node). It is a strange behavior I have never seen before.

I was trying the above code using Chrome v79 and Edge 79 on the Mac. If the same code was tried on Firefox v72, the event will not fire. You can set the listener up, and then do a `window.speechSynthesis.getVoices()` and it will return an empty array, but then that event will fire, so you have to call `window.speechSynthesis.getVoices()` twice in order to get the voices. But Firefox caches the result, so even when you refresh the page and do a `window.speechSynthesis.getVoices()` then it will return an array of voices right away.

So combining the behavior on Chrome and Firefox, if you have to make it work, then you have to do:

```
let voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();

if (voices.length === 0) { 
  window.speechSynthesis.addEventListener('voiceschanged', function(ev) {
    voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();
  });
}
```

that is `window.speechSynthesis.getVoices()` needs to be called twice. How would you understand this behavior? Usually, we would think of calling the function once, but not twice to obtain something.

Comment: FWIW, on macOS the list is populated immediately. So at best this is implementation dependent and may be an optimisation strategy in *some* browsers on *some* platforms.

Comment: "Requests for lists of things" is among the topics marked as "Don't ask about…" in the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: @Quentin ok I modified the question. It is just something quite weird that I hope to understand more about.